# Getting java.io.FileWriter@xxxxxxxx at the end of a text file

Tags: java, java-io

While writing into a file from jTextArea, I always get *java.io.FileWriter@xxxxxxxx* at the end while xxxxxxxx is a random hexadecimal value.

How could I remove it please?

Here is my code:

```
try (FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("./output.txt");        
        BufferedWriter output= new BufferedWriter(fstream);){
            Writer info = fstream.append(jTextArea.getText());
            output.write("" + info);
}catch (IOException e){
       e.printStackTrace();
}


Thank you
```

Comment: Why are you writing the writer to the file? Solution: don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        Writer info = fstream.append(jTextArea.getText());
        output.write("" + info);  // <------ this is what is wrong
```

The return value of append is just `this`. This style of API is called fluent and is done to allow this kind of code:

```
  writer.append("a").append("b").append("c");
```

That last line you can just remove. What it does is this:

```
  output.write(info.toString());
```

The FileWriter.toString() is using the default implementation which just outputs the name of the class of the object and the identity hashcode of that object.

`append` already writes to the Writer.

That being said, if you have a BufferedWriter, then use it instead of the FileWriter directly. Just make sure to close the writer(s) afterwards.